# Sharing ground and power across circuits

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I'm just beginning with circuits, so pardon if this is elementary, but I couldn't figure it out.

I'm building a speaker joining several circuit boards together:

- a trinket pro
- a class d amp
- an FM radio chip.

The trinket controls the class **d amp** and **FM radio** via I<sup>2</sup>C bus(sda/scl).

All these boards need connections to 5V power and ground. On a breadboard this is easy.

Currently, I'm making a rats nest of wires where I twist 2 or 3 wires into one and then solder them.

However, what is the best practice to create power rails and ground rails multiple chips can plug into? Should I be using a perfboard or other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a ***Prototyping Board***. Most of them have pre-drilled holes and pre-existing copper tracks.

There are different kinds, it is often just down to your personal preference which one you use.

This one is useful for transferring the layout directly from a breadboard:

[image]

This one, "Stripboard", is useful when you have several buses, such as multiple power rails, or signals like clocks, data buses, etc:

[image]

There are some other ones where there are no copper tracks on the underneath, just single pads on each hole which enable soldering; a wire is wrapped on pins underneath, and a route created directly to the destination, then the wire soldered:

[image]

Other boards not shown might include PCI boards etc for direct insertion into expansion slots on PC motherboards, and so on. There are also some meant for small-pitch surface-mount chips.